# How to implement "Drag-Select" functionaility within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I would like to implement some "Drag-select" functionality into a project of mine but i'm unsure how to implement it.

The creation of the selection area is not a problem, it's the capturing of elements within the area itself which is confusing me.

Comment: Can you provide some more info on the requirement?

Comment: Yeah, i should really have stated that i will be using Prototype JS and Scriptaculous to implement this.

I was more looking for any general concepts on how to implement the functionality of selecting any DOM node that the selection may cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery example found here.

[Selectable Demo](http://view.jquery.com/tags/ui/1.5b2/demos/ui.selectable.html)

Comment: Thank you, i've not seen this example - will take a look at the source and see how they have implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery there are some plugins that do this operation. Anyway you can check if the position of the element is contained into the selection area coordinates and, if it is, you select it.

Answer (score 0):

Script.aculo.us has a nice implementation of [drag-n-drop](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/draggable), but then you have to include this rather large library. Or you could investigate how they done it for that matter, since its open-source.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm already aware of the drag-n-drop functionality withing Script.aculo.us. I am already taking advantage of this to great the selection area itself, what i need to know is how i can capture any DOM elements within that capture area.